# Interesting electrical ceiling box with downward pass through bolts

Tags: electrical, ceiling, ceiling-fan, mounting, junction-box

I'm trying to mount a heavy ceiling fan but ran into a unique ceiling box I've never seen before. Two bolts come down from the metal horizontal piece and pass through the plastic box.

This was the first set of pictures before I realized the box wasn't mounted by anything:

[image]

Then I realized it came off so here's the next set of pics:

[image]

Is this safe to mount a heavy fan to? Should I get nylon locking nuts and just secure with those bolts?

Comment: What markings (if any) are present on the inside of the box?

Comment: There is a cross-brace visible in the second set of photos, if that rests on the joists in the ceiling then you are fine.

Comment: To emphasise on @ratchetfreak's answer: try to find out how that cross brace is mounted.  You might be able to stick your phone in there and make some flash photos to find out.

Comment: As it stands right now, it is not strong enough for fan.

Comment: In the 2nd pic, the bolt is attached to a bar. That bar is for mounting the box. It is then attached to another bracket that runs between the ceiling joists to hold it in place. IMHO, that bracket does _NOT_ look like it is sturdy enough to hold up a ceiling fan. Compare the shape/size of that bracket piece to [this old work ceiling fan box](https://www.lowes.com/pd/RACO-1-Gang-Silver-Steel-New-Work-Old-Work-Standard-Ceiling-Fan-Ceiling-Electrical-Box/3127059) (Lowe's link - just an example).

Comment: The bolts also don't look thick enough to be able to withstand the slight but perpetual wobble of a fan (there is no triangle/third bolt, so they'll be able to swing a bit). OP also specifically mentions a HEAVY ceiling fan, so I'm pretty sure that the answer will indeed be a *"no"*.

Comment: I would still investigate what's above that ceiling (smartphone/flash) and how strong/sturdy it is though, perhaps there are other options to hang it off of. Zack, how high is the actual ceiling above this false one?

Comment: @ratchetfreak yes the cross bar is mounted to joists. So what's the best method to mount then? Secure the box to the bolts using nylon locking nuts and then mount to the box? Or mount directly to the bolts?

Comment: @MiG ok here you go, it looks like it's pretty darn solid: https://imgur.com/a/GnKnyfF [Video of bracket going to joists and images below]

Comment: If the box is rated for a ceiling fan, it will say so inside the box. Check inside.

Comment: @JACK it does say that its rated for a fan

Comment: @Zack Then you're good to go. The cross bar probably turns to expand and tighten it up against the joists so give it a turn to ensure it's tight.

Comment: @Zack -- the box will have labeling on it that says its maximum weight capacity -- what does it have to say?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me that what you have there is a ceiling fan mounting kit already installed. You could:

- try to determine the make or model of the mount, so as to determine its weight capacity
- verify that it appears to have been installed correctly
- get a pair of nuts that fit the threaded studs. It's been a while since I installed one of these, so I don't recall whether they ship with any kind of locking nut, but it seems like you couldn't go wrong in choosing to use the locking style.

"Heavy" means different things to different people. Based on the small glimpse of it we can see, I'd say it looks like the sort that would easily handle an "average" ceiling fan up to 72 inches diameter or so.